# Is there a word for the 'art' of creating amulets?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is my first question on this site, so if it is off-topic I apologize.

Is there a word for the practice/art of creating amulets, talismans, magical tokens, or the like? For example, 'wizardry' is practicing magic as a wizard, and 'wandistry' is the use of magical wands, so is there a word in a similar vein such as 'talismanistry'?

I would want to use it like this: "The two major branches of magic are wandistry and [insert word]."

I think 'wandistry' is a noun (and thus this word would also be a noun) because it is like 'medicine' or 'dentistry': it is an occupation/art. If such a word doesn't exist (I'm pretty sure 'wandistry' doesn't exist either) any convincing made-up word is perfectly sufficient.

Some dictionary searches I've tried:
[OneLook with keywords "make amulet"](http://onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=make%20amulet)
[OneLook with keywords "make talisman"](http://onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=make%20talisman)

Additionally, normal Google and Ecosia (which has results provided by Bing) searches turn up nothing but instruction sets for rituals to actually make magic amulets, which I'm not interested in.

**Edit:**
In my case I'm specifically referring to the process of creating amulets, as in magical gemstones. The use of talismans/magical tokens as examples was not well thought out by me.

Comment: If you're happy inventing "wandistry", what's wrong with "talismanistry" or "amuletry"?

Comment: @KillingTime I tried 'talismanistry', but it just didn't seem to flow very well, and felt very awkward to read and say. However, I didn't think of 'amuletry', and it sounds pretty good, so I suggest you put it as an answer. I'll give it a day or two to see if anyone comes up with anything else/better, but if not, I'll accept that one.

Comment: Do they make the amulet / talisman magically as a magic item (ie in one go), or is it created first by a jeweller/gemsmith and then enchanted/imbued with the magic property later?

Comment: @Smock It's rather ambiguous. They have several stones and imbue them into one item in one single action, so you could say that because the stones are already finished they are just doing the magic, but you could also say that because they are combining the stones they are doing everything in one go. Although I don't think the difference would matter too much.

Comment: @Nik3141 Ah ok, that makes sense - they're not just taking everyday objects and enchanting then. They are actually creating something as the imbue it with magic (and so it could potentially lose it's magic by breaking?)

Comment: @Smock Yeah. My use of 'talismans' was not well thought through, as that implies, as you said, everyday objects. My thoughts were more on the amulet side, specifically meaning a magical *stone* which could break if smashed and is essentially a gemstone, but magical.

Comment: Amuletrics. Talismanry.

Comment: Amulets are things on necklaces, made by a necklace maker. The stone or object is considered to have magical properties.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert on fields of magic but in a couple of cases where such a word would likely be used, even if uncommon, the authors chose "crafting". It was obvious from context and some uses that they meant crafting magical items. Even so this is evidence of the lack of such a word as much as it's a suggestion.

Comment: Ok. There being no official word, I think I'll go with 'amuletry'.

Comment: If you're going with "amuletry", it probably better to give that as an answer and accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

> Artificer

Meaning someone who specialises in creating *artifacts* such as magical trinkets

[D&D Reference](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer)

Comment: This is a strange coincidence because I actually needed three words, 'wandistry', 'amuletry', and something for putting magical power into objects. I'll probably use 'artificery' for the third one.

Comment: You have posted a non-word. You forgot the r.

Comment: Thanks @Lambie, not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Try making [Phylactery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylactery) into what you need, like **Phylacterism**

(nb: Although D&D has a very narrow usage of Phylactery, it can mean any amulet or charm).

Comment: This would work great except it doesn't sound a ton like it is related to making amulets *at first*, and sounds like it has something to do with plants. Definitely a good word, but I'm looking for a word which has a pretty obvious link to amulets (to the non D&D initiated), so I might use 'amuletry' instead.

Comment: Right. As per the original question, this is for amulets, talismans, and charms, not just amulets.

Answer (score 1):

I am a practicing magician (not some Penn and Teller style performer but someone with actual magical powers) so I can tell you what I at least (and others in the industry) call these different things.

A talisman or amulet or other objet d'art needs to have spells put on them *during* manufacture. Sometimes afterwards is fine but it works best if the magic is done during manufacture.  This imbues the object with magical characteristics that stay with the object. Most talismans or amulets are made by

> jewelers

and the process is called

> jewel making.

The magic part of it is purely secondary.

If the artwork is more substantial than a piece of jewelry (too bulky to be worn on a person), then they are made by:

> artists, artisans, or sculptors.

If the process of manufacture is purely magical, say, in creating an object out of thin air, then working alone I call myself a:

> magician.

No self-respecting adept uses the children's grandiose terms of 'wizard' or 'witch'. All that Harry Potter stuff is fiction, literally.

For those who do 'wandmaking', called **wandmakers**, wands aren't considered talismans at all. In the ontology of artifacts, yes, strictly speaking, wands -are- talismans, but nobody using a wand thinks like that. It's like thinking [a hamburger is a sandwich](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246580/is-a-hamburger-considered-a-sandwich), it may strictly follow the rules but you just don't think that way.

Comment: You put spells on products? How insane is that?

Comment: @Lambie Look man, I don't make the rules, that's just how it works.

Comment: amulets are not manufactured. They are made. Let's get the English right at least, shall we?